# Which is correct, "to take refuge in" or "to take refuge with"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

Concerning refuge with a higher existence such as an Omnipotent being, what is more befitting to use, English wise:

1. To take refuge in [Omnipotent being]
2. To take refuge with [Omnipotent being]

Grammatically, which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take refuge  has both literal and figurative meanings.

Among the literal meanings are to seek safety in a place and to seek safety in the company of another person or persons.

With the former we *tend* to use "in":

**In the storm, they took refuge *in* a train station.**

When referring to the latter, we *tend* to use "with":

**The police determined that the fugitive had taken refuge *with* a motorcycle gang.**

In the first, the place or building provides the safety.  In the second, being in the company of those other people provides the safety.

I have emphasized *tend* because these are not absolute divisions.  You will find in religious writing, for example, "in" and "with" used almost interchangeably:

Take refuge in the Lord.

Take refuge with the Heavenly Father.

The figurative meaning refers to a kind of spiritual security, and the Deity is often understood metaphorically as a place of refuge, a "mighty fortress" for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you take refuge with someone then that means that you both take refuge.

Example

I took refuge with my family until the storm had passed.

It is a matter of philosophy whether you take refuge *in* an omnipotent being. I would say that, for example, you take refuge *in* God's mercy.

[Google ngram: take refuge in God](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20refuge%20in%20God&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20refuge%20in%20God%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

I got this far:

If refuge refers to *safety* one would use *in*.

One finds safety *in* an [Omniscient being]
(Unless you are hiding under the table together with [Omniscient being]).

If refuge refers to *shelter* one could use any preposition of place:

- Homeless people take refuge in subway shelters.
- Julian Assange has taken refuge inside an embassy.
- I take refuge with my mom.
- We took refuge under the table during the earthquake.
- She took refuge across the street, in the cafe.